# Linux - How can I merge two csv files?

Tags: file, csv, merge

**file a.csv**

```
11111, 22222
33333, 44444
55555, 66666
77777, 45454
```

**file b.csv**

```
11111, 12121
33333, 44444
55555, 88888
```

**expected result**

```
11111, 12121
33333, 44444
55555, 88888
77777, 45454
```

file B's key column is subset A (ex : 11111, 33333, 55555)
How can I merge the two files into a third c.csv?

A is the target, put the value of B

Comment: What language do you use, what code do you have?

Comment: I would set IFS=$'\n' and loop through file a. I would use cut -d',' - f1 to grab the first value and grep file b using a regex to match the beginning of the line to the first comma. I'd grab the output and direct both values into the third file. If you need to process big files, I suggest using Perl or Python as the method I described is somewhat inefficient.

Comment: Usually this is done in a script using a language like perl or python that supports "associative arrays" or "dictionaries" , i.e. arrays with a string index, by reading each file into an array and then looping through the keys of array a to print the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 cat a.csv b.csv | sort | uniq > c.csv
```

Comment: This doesn't replace rows from a with rows from b, which was the goal.  After the sort, it is entirely possible that uniq removes the duplicates from b, not a, in producing c.